# Learning JavaScript : display all firstnames with B as first letter

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript for the first time and I would like to know why my code doesn't work.
I have Python/Django knowledges.

#### Objective :

I have to create a list of names and I have to display only firstnames which begins by 'B' letter.

#### My script :

```
var listNames = ['Paul', 'Bruno', 'Arthur', 'Bert', 'José']

for (var i in listNames) {
  if (i.substr(0, 1) === 'B') {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

But this code doesn't display something.

Comment: use `for ... of` instead of `for ... in`.

Comment: Oh thank you ! I have to see the difference between `for ... of` and `for .. in`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), not [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) as it's for iterate objects

*And the `i.substr(0, 1) === 'B'` could be replaced with [`i.startsWith('B')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)*

```js
var listNames = ['Paul', 'Bruno', 'Arthur', 'Bert', 'José']

listNames.forEach( i => {
  if (i.startsWith('B')) {
    console.log(i);
  }
})
```

---

Or [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```js
var listNames = ['Paul', 'Bruno', 'Arthur', 'Bert', 'José']

for (i of listNames) {
  if (i.startsWith('B')) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

---

Yet another option could be to use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and reduce the original array into a new.

```js
var listNames = ['Paul', 'Bruno', 'Arthur', 'Bert', 'José']

var new_listNames = listNames.filter( i => i.startsWith('B') )

console.log(new_listNames);
```

Comment: if I have `for ... of` and `i[0] === "B"` is it bad written or acceptable ?

Comment: @Deadpool Doing `i[0]` is pretty much the same as `i.split("")[0]`, so instead use what I suggested or `i.charAt(0) === 'B'`, they are better and more readable with what goes on.

Comment: @Deadpool And if you are going to loop an array with thousands of items, make a test and check which one preforms the best, if not, make your code readable instead.

Comment: Ok perfect ! As I don't know all Javascript classes, I used something which is "universal". But I'm glat to learn this new class !

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `listNames[i]` as `i` gives you the `index` of array `listNames`. Then use `charAt(0)` to the value of the array to check for the first character as `B`.

```js
var listNames = ['Paul', 'Bruno', 'Arthur', 'Bert', 'José']

for (var i in listNames) {
  if (listNames[i].charAt(0) === 'B') {
    console.log(listNames[i]);
  }
}
```

If you want to use the values of array that start with `B` further in your code as a separate array then use `filter()`:

```js
var listNames = ['Paul', 'Bruno', 'Arthur', 'Bert', 'José']

var res = listNames.filter(item => item.charAt(0) === 'B');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @ASDFGerte the answer points out the mistake in OP's code of why it is not working. OP says `But this code doesn't display something.`

Comment: If OP use the proper `for...` loop, they won't need to do something like `listNames[i]`, as that is how to do with objects. (unless the old `for(var i;...)` is used of course)

Comment: Your answer is correct @AnkitAgarwal but I would like to use `for ... in/of` because I'm just beginning JavaScript lessons :/

Comment: @Deadpool sure that is your wish. I just pointed the error you had in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
listNames.forEach((el) => {if (el.charAt(0) == 'B') console.log(el)});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to loop over arrays.

```
const listNames = ['Paul', 'Bruno', 'Arthur', 'Bert', 'José']
for (const name of listNames) {
  if (name[0] === "B") {
    console.log(name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var listNames = ['Paul', 'Bruno', 'Arthur', 'Bert', 'José']

for (var i of listNames) {
  if (i.substr(0, 1) === 'B') {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```